# I'm having trouble understanding the concept on how to get around this task, can someone assist me?

Tags: java

I have been looking at this for about 30 minutes now, I can't find a way on how to approach this.

> A digital control system is considered stable if its poles are inside the unit circle. The poles refer to the roots of the denominator in a control system's transfer funciton. On the other hand, the unit circle is a circle in the complex plane whose center is at the origin and whose radius is one (1). If the denominator of the transfer function is, az^2 + bz + c, determine whether it is stalbe or not after the user inputs the coefficients. **Your program should show the roots (rectangular or polar, depending on your preference) and stability condition**. Assume that the coeffecients are *real numbers*.

Here's what I've done so far...

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Problem # 1
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        int a,b,c;
        double d;
        
        System.out.println("Given the equation: ax^2 + bx + c");
        System.out.print("Input value for a: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input value for b: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input value for c: ");
        c = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        
        d = ((Math.pow(b, 2))-(4*a*c));
        double real = (-b) / (2*a);
        double imaginary = Math.sqrt(-d)/(2*a);
        
        System.out.print("The complex conjugates are " + df.format(real) + " + " + df.format(imaginary) +"i");
        System.out.print(" and " + df.format(real) + " - " + df.format(imaginary) +"i");
        if(d <= 0) {
                
                
                System.out.println("\nThe Stability condition is stable");
                }
                else {
                    
                    System.out.println("\nThe Stability Condition is unstable");
        }
        int zero=0,neg=0,pos=0;
        if (a < 0 ) {
            neg = neg + 1;
            }
            else if (a> 0 ) {
                pos = pos + 1;
            }
            else if (a == 0) {
                zero = zero + 1;
            }
        if ( b < 0 ) {
            neg = neg + 1;
            }
            else if ( b > 0 ) {
                pos = pos + 1;
            }
            else if (b ==0){
                zero = zero + 1;
            }
        if ( c < 0 ) {
            neg = neg + 1;
            }
            else if ( c > 0 ) {
                pos = pos + 1;
            }
            else if (c ==0){
                zero = zero + 1;
            }
        System.out.println("the number of zero is " + zero);
        System.out.println("the number of Positive is " + pos);
        System.out.println("the number of Negative is " + neg);
        
            }
            
        }
```

Note: I'm fairly new to this, it would be a great help if someone can help a fellow newbie :))

Comment: It might help if you'd show some more effort, e.g. by not providing the task as an image but actual text. Additionally you should show what you've tried so far, even if it's just thoughts how you could go about solving it, and where/why you failed. Finally, you might want to read [ask].

Comment: ohh okay okay got it @Thomas